# My Character Speed is going to Infinity [Using Time.unscaledTime]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

So i'm making a game where you can slow the time but the player's speed is the same so he's not affected by the time and i used the method with Time.unscaledTime caused it worked with sprinting

```
PlayerSpeed = (PlayerSpeed * Time.unscaledTime * 1.2f);
```

but now when i try do this (also tried other ways and without * 1.2f)
the players speed goes up to Infinity.

why is it doing this? while this

```
NormalSprintSpeed = SprintSpeed + CrawlerSprintSpeed * Time.unscaledTime;
```

is Working Fine?

Comment: `Time.unscaledTime` returns the number of seconds since the game started, so the speed of your character is going to increase the longer the game is running. Did you maybe mean to use `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be fine because `Time.unscaledTime` returns the number of seconds since the game started.

If you want to slow the time for all objects then you need to use [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).

Comment: Now speed of my Player is 0 ;/

Comment: i forgot to add a bit more about my code here it is


`PlayerSpeed = PlayerSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
Time.timeScale = 0.25f;
Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;
`

Comment: Do nothing with `PlayerSpeed` and just increase or decrease `Time.timeScale` value. That is all.

Comment: if i would do this then the player would be also slower and i want like in the dishonored that everything is slowed but NOT the Player

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the question. Decrease `Time.timeScale` and change velocity of player's rigidbody. `newVelocity = actualVelocity * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * (1 + (1-Time.timeScale)))`. This will increase velocity to "normal"